# Where should I make a GUI program auto start as daemon after auto signing in to Gnome

Tags: automation, boot, gnome

I have a GUI program written in Java. And it seems it could only be executed in Gnome environment which my box had installed.

The box was set to boot at init 5 (which is Gnome)

I tried to place command line to start the program in /etc/rd.d/rc.local, and as it seems, it did not start at all. Probably lack of GUI environment as a result Java was refuse to run. Do I really have to execute it manually after signing in to Gnome? Is there anyway to tell Gnome to automate it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/08/add-an-application-to-gnomes-autostart/